# No value given for one or more required parameters. C#

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, datatable, oledbcommand

I have a C# program and I made a code for subtracting the amount of sold products from the amount of these products in the stock (access datatable) so I used this code :

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
      OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Update BookInserting set Amount = Amount - '" + Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells[1].Value) + "' where BookName = " + r.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "", connection);
      connection.Open();
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
      connection.Close();
}
```

but when I run it gives me this error :
(No value given for one or more required parameters) .
I tried solving it several times but failed, I hope you can help me solve it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: do not concatenate strings to build sql commands. Use parameters.

Comment: At a super quick glance, it would help to post from where this is called and the line the error occurs on perhaps

Comment: you are opening and closing connection for every grid row. you can open connection before foreach and close after foreach.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss the error occurs in the execution line.

Comment: what is `r.Cells[0].Value.ToString()` and is it a number always otherwise that `BookName = 'some value'` will need to be wrapped in single quotes to be a proper SQL statement

Comment: I would somewhat strongly suggest you make the values parameters for the SQL and call that using parameters.

Comment: @PXLDesiner put breakpoint on execution line. Once the execution reaches at breakpoint, take the query from command object and run on your database. Check there what is the issue.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss no r.Cells[0].Value is a string

Comment: @PXLDesiner Would `Update BookInserting set Amount = Amount - 5 where BookName = The BookName Here` be a valid SQL statement? No, no it wouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is probably caused by Access unable to recognize some part of your query as an object of the underlying table (or the table itself).
This problem and a more serious one called Sql Injection could be avoided using parameters. (And a side benefit your code becomes a lot clearer without all those strings concatenations)

So let's try to change your code in this way:

```
// String sql with parameters placeholders 
string cmdText = @"Update BookInserting 
                   set Amount = Amount - @amt
                   where BookName = @book";

connection.Open();

// Just build the command just one time outside the loop and 
// add the two parameters required (without a value and in the exact order
// expected by the placeholders
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, connection);
command.Parameters.Add("@amt", OleDbType.Integer);
command.Parameters.Add("@book", OleDbType.VarWChar);

// Inside the loop just change the parameters values and execute
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    // If the cell with the parameter for the WHERE 
    // clause is invalid skip the update
    if(!r.IsNewRow && r.Cells[0].Value != null  
                   && r.Cells[0].Value.ToString() != "")
    {
       cmd.Parameters["@amt"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells[1].Value);
       cmd.Parameters["@book"].Value = r.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
       command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

}
connection.Close();
```

Final note. A connection object should be created each time you require it. From your code it is not clear if this is the case. Use the following pattern. ([Using Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement))

```
using(OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(....))
{
    ... code that uses the connection ....
} // <- here the connection is closed and disposed
```

Comment: Pretty much where I was going with this but teaching to fish with questions a bit first

Comment: Alternate would perhaps be table valued parameters and speed this up perhaps but that is outside the question scope

Comment: In the 45th line an error that says: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." occurs

Comment: And the line 45 is?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss lot of effort for small gain. However this is Access. I doubt you have TVP as an option here.

Comment: @Steve it is : cmd.Parameters["@book"].Value = r.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
sorry for not mentioning

Comment: Ah, I was looking too fast at the SQL and not the tag for MS Access, good point!

Comment: @PXLDesiner this means that your _r.Cells[0].Value_ is null and you cannot call ToString on a null object. You can probably see the empty cell/cells on screen

Comment: @Steve Wellthe value that is in the r.Cells[0] is basically a ComboBox item

Comment: OR check for them `r.Cells[0].HasValue && r.Cells[1].HasValue` (posting this without knowing much about the source)

Comment: it is inserted in the DGV using dt.Rows.Add(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())

Comment: Of course if the cell is empty you cannot run any query because the value is used to find the record to update. So your priority should be to ensure that every rows has the first cell not empty or null. Not a problem of this part of the code. unless you want to skip the update in case the cell is empty or null

Comment: i checked if it was null or not inside the loop with this code :
if (r.Cells[0] == null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("nope");
                }
and no messagebox appeared so that means it is not null and the error :(Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)
still appears

Comment: Please use the debugger to see if your loop doesn't continue after the last visible row. If the NRE happens on that line there is only one explanation. The cell value is null.

Comment: Ok now the error occurs in the Parameters["@book"].Value which is inside the loop even though I tried inserting a value manually to the datagridview and made sure that there was no null cell and it still gave me the error so I tried changing the Parameters["@book"].Value to the value of "Test" and there was no problem but when I put the value of r.Cells[0].Value it gives the error but again I am sure that the cell is not null i am only trying on a single row so I can see all the cells

Comment: Did you check with the debugger? Do not rely on visual. The debugger will tell you if it is looping too much or what value is inside that cell. Also check if the row has the property IsNewRow == true and skip if it is true

Comment: @steve how to skip ?

Comment: See the answer. Add another condition _if(!row.IsNewRow && ....)_

Comment: I don't really know why but the error stopped when I changed the r.Cells[0].Value.ToString to Convert.ToString(r.Cells[0].Value) ._.